# Apache Velocity: Checking the count of array

Tags: apache, velocity, cisco-ios

I am working with Cisco Prime Infrastructure and need to create a CLI template for mass deployment to some switches.  Prime uses Apache Velocity for its CLI content to script.  I have run into a problem where I am running some code that loops through the VLANS on a switch and performs action per VLAN.  The code works fine if the switch has multiple VLANS, but fails if it only has one.  Example:

Switch1 consists of Vlan 1, so the array looks like this [Vlan1]

Switch2 consists of Vlan 1, Vlan 2, Vlan 3, array looks like [Vlan1, Vlan2, Vlan3]

The code:

```
#foreach($vlan in $VlanName)
interface $vlan
no ip helper-address
#end
```

$VlanName is defined in the Prime Database and returns the array of vlans on each switch.  The above will work on Switch2 but will fail on Switch1.  Is there a way in Apache Velocity to do a check to see if the array holds more than a single value?  I would like to do an IF statement that changes the code to something like this:

```
#if ($VlanName.count = 1)
interface $VlanName
no ip helper-address
#else
#foreach($vlan in $VlanName)
interface $vlan
no ip helper-address
#end
```

Is this possible in Velocity?

Answer (score 1):

You can always get the size by using invoking the `size()` method on the object.

```
#set($size = $VlanName.size())
#if($size == 1)
    Only one
#end
```